# facebook like event not work

Tags: android, facebook-like

This is my html colde . I want to fire fb like event() when click like button.

```
<html xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
 <head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
 </head>
 <body >
 Facebook Like Test!     
 <div id="fb-root"></div>

 <script type="text/javascript">
 window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
 FB.init({
  appId      : '578995225546612',
  status     : true,
  cookie: true,
  xfbml      : true
  });
console.log("I m in inint()");  
   FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(href, widget) {
   alert('testing :)');
  console.log("chan you like me !!!");
   }); 
  };

  (function(d, s, id) {
   var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
   if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
   js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
   js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
   fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>  
  </script>
  <fb:like href="https://www.facebook.com/99sanay" layout="standard" action="like" show_faces="true" share="false"></fb:like></body>
```

I try to get facebook like event . But when click like button ,nothing happen . The following message get.

[image]